# tfs unable to browse projects

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) server {MyProject}.visualstudio.com. I'm able to connect to the server, map the project, even receive a review request, but I can't see my team projects under DefaultCollection. 
Currently when I'm opening the Source Control Explorer I'm only seeing 
{MyProject}.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection
     underlying projects are missing, but my user is in project team members list.

**What I missed, what I should do else to be able to browse my projects, get and work with them?**

Note: My account was not a microsoft account. I received an email to join the visual studio after tfs administrator added my email as the project team member. I follow to the link and I create a new account during VS sign up using that email and then successfully signed in.

[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by the "Access Level" that the Admin assigned to your account.

When your account is assigned as "[Stakeholder](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-feature-matrix-vs)", you can only access to "Work" section, cannot access to "Code". If you want the access to "Code", you need to ask your Admin to change the access level of your account.

Comment: Change to what? MSDN Subscriber? some of members have access level basic and after changing to basic level that particular user are beeing able to manage the code, but what about the users for which there is no basic access level to choose?

Comment: @artos "Basic" or "MSDN Subscriber". And there can be only 5 "Basic" users in one VSTS Account. Refer to this link for details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/assign-licenses-to-users-vs

Answer (score 1):

Have the TFS Admin review your user's rights to the code in the team project.  Generally we add users to the Contributor role for the project.

You should also try hitting the Refresh button (third from the right) on the Source Control Explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and as usual Microsoft has not useful error. Here is step by step tutorial to fix it.

### The problem

[image]

### Solution

This is related to user permissions. Note two things

1. If you are using 5 user free version, make sure to select user as "**Basic user**". Free version allows only basic membership.
2. Then go to Security setting, expand to see "Team Foundation Administrators" and add the new user this. This should resolve the browe project issue.
   [image]